# Fluid layout not working in Internet Explorer 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on  floating boxes responsibly using CSS, My objective is to make it work in Internet Explorer 7 and 8. Can I achieve this in Jquery?

If anybody could be of assistance this would be a massive help !!!

Here my my fiddle. please update :)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZuJW2/

```
/* =============================================================================
BOXS RESPONSIVE
========================================================================== */

#examples {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 970px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#examples ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}
#examples ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#examples ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#examples ul li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#examples ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
#examples ul li:nth-child(1n+1) {
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 3.85%;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
  #examples ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 48.08%;
  }
  #examples ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #examples ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #examples ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-left: 51.93%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  #examples ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #examples ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 22.11%;
  }
  #examples ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #examples ul li:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #examples ul li:nth-child(4n+2) {
    margin-left: 25.96%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #examples ul li:nth-child(4n+3) {
    margin-left: 51.93%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #examples ul li:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-left: 77.89%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to handle IE7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Respond JS](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). IE8 and below do not support CSS media queries or min/max-width, you need to use a polyfill for this to work.

You can include Respond JS in your document for IE 8 and below by adding the following code to your `<head>` tag.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="/PATH-TO-JS/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```